# Invalid Property when applying combine transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I use the tranform property with one transformation everything works fine but I get 'invalid property' when they are combined. I'm testing with Opera

Does not work

```
transform: translate(300,0px) rotate(90deg);
```

Does work

```
transform: translate(300,0px);
```

Comment: You are not using `px` values in `300`, I think thats the problem.

Comment: Yep that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `px` values instead of single.

Do:

```
transform: translate(300px, 0px) rotate(90deg);
```

Instead of:

```
transform: translate(300, 0px) rotate(90deg);
```

Hope this helps!